# cant make local database because Error: FIle/etc/my.cnf doesnt exist

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064, my.cnf

i want to make local database on workbench and when i configure local management it was said

```
Check if /etc/my.cnf can be accessed
Operation failed: File /etc/my.cnf doesn't exist
```

so i've used this option on my terminal

```
sudo cp my-huge.cnf /etc/my.cn
```

and it was said

```
cp: cannot stat 'my-huge.cnf': No such file or directory
```

when i check my support-files, it was not any single of my.cnf files, so i just confused why my mysql dont have any my.cnf files.

Answer (score 0):

mysql doesn't include .cnf files because the default configuration is reasonably sane.

When my-huge.cnf existed it was written in the year ~2000 and its huge definition didn't change ever. (~4 cpus and ~1G ram - ha, there was even a huge-4G.cnf file for when "huge" wasn't enough)

If something is requiring `/etc/my.cnf` to exist, create it as an empty file (e.g. `touch /etc/my.cnf`).

Comment: so what should i do next? sorry i didnt understand of what you said